# Sort images by most recent and filter for images with likes > x

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram, instafeedjs

In [instafeed.js](https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js), I have the ability to `sortBy` tagged pictures either by `most-liked` or `most-recent`. Those options are mutually exclusive. I am trying to find a middle ground to do both. I would like to sort by `most-recent` and then display those that have `likes > x amount`. How can I achieve this in instafeed.js?

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
  target: 'instafeed',
  get: 'tagged',
  tagName: 'dog',
  limit: '10',
  sortBy: 'most-recent',
  resolution: 'standard_resolution',
  clientId: 'xxxxx', 
  template:'<div class="tile"><div class="text"><b>{{likes}} &hearts; </b>{{model.user.full_name}}</div><img class="item" src="{{image}}"></div>',
  filter: function(image) {
    //filter for recent images with most like
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/issues/21 the `image` parameter in the filter function has attribute `likes`. So you should be able to do something like

```
filter: function(image) {
  return image.likes.count >= minAmount;
}
```